# Taking input in bash from the output on terminal

Tags: bash

The following is copied from my terminal:

```
home:Doc$ grep AAA: testfile.txt
         1         5         5         9        90  8.0 -7.0  1.5       500 b, AAA: (  9  9  5)
```

In a bash script I want to include the grep command as shown above. And then I want to assign the "500" in the output to a variable "var1". Is there a way to do it? So my bash script would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep AAA: testfile.txt

# I want to assign var1 = 500
```

Or is there a way to take the input directly from the file "testfile.txt" ?

Please suggest me some ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: will record always follow the format `500 b,`

Comment: will the value you want (500) always be the 9th "word" of output. If so, `var=$(awk '/AAA/{print $9}' file); echo "var=$var"` . If not, then please don't reply in comments, but improve the sample data, required output and description of problem **in the body of the question above**. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, it will. But I want to do it just one time (i.e. take the value 500). And after taking the value of the variable "var1 " as 500, the file testfile.txt will change.

Comment: @shelter. Thanks, that worked

Comment: Work your way thru the [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and you'll sail thru problems like this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
x="1         5         5         9        90  8.0 -7.0  1.5       500 b, AAA: (  9  9  5)"
y=$(echo $x | cut -d " " -f 9)
```

will do it. Test with

```
y=$(echo $x | cut -d " " -f 9) && echo $y //500
```

so in your context let `x=$(grep AAA: testfile.txt)`